# Trying to understand an example of the local system

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

I'm reading through Szamuely's [Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521888506).

Szamuely defines complex local systems as locally constant sheafs of finite dimensional complex vector spaces.
I'm stuck on the very first example he gives:

Let $D \subset \mathbb C$ be a connected open subset. Consider over $D$ a homogeneous linear differential equation:
$$y^{(n)} + a_1y^{(n-1)} + \ldots + a_ny = 0, $$
with $a_i$ holomorphic functions on $D$.

For open subset $U \subset D$ we define $S(U)$ as local solutions of the equation over $U$. Szamuely claims $S$ is a local system.

For me it's clear that each $S(U)$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space, and it's clear that $S$ really defines a sheaf.
The problem is I can't see why it's locally constant?

By definition, I must show that every point $x \in D$ has an open neighborhood $V$ such that $S|_V$ ($S$ restricted to V) is isomorphic to a  constant sheaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a point $x \in D$ and $V$ is a disk around $x$. On $V$, a solution $g$ is uniquely determined by $(g(x), g'(x), \dots, g^{(n-1)}(x))$, so sending $g$ to its $n-1$ first derivatives defines an isomorphism $S(V) \cong \mathbb C^n_V$, where $\mathbb C^n_V$ is the constant sheaf on $V$ with stalk $\mathbb C^n$.